# RXweb formbuild group in array not working

Tags: angular, node-java

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jvpsc2?file=src/app/prop-array-createblank.component.ts

```
export const addressFormGroup = () => {
  return <RxFormGroup>formBuilder.group({
    country: [null, [RxwebValidators.required()]],
    city: [null, [RxwebValidators.required(), RxwebValidators.unique()]],
  });
};

export const User = (res: any = null) => {
  let formObject: any = {
    emailAddress: ['', [RxwebValidators.required()]],
    addresses: formBuilder.array([addressFormGroup()]),
  };

  // create form
  const form: any = formBuilder.group(formObject);

  if (res) {
    form.patchModelValue(res);
  }

  form.commit();

  return form;
};
```

Error: instanceContainer is undefined

Unable to display error. Open your browser's console to view.

commit() is not working properly in array value